# How to stop service that contains a thread immidiately in activity

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-activity

Recently, I'm creating an app with a service at background. I would like when I open my app, the service will stop and when I close my app, the service will start. And I found a way to do that. I put the "startService" in "onDestroy" and the "stopService" in "onCreate" of the MainActivity ( this activity is always the first started and the last destroyed activity). But only the startService works fine, the stopService make my MainActivity become a white blank Screen when I start my app.

MyService.class

```
 Thread t;
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  shouldContinue = true;

    t = new Thread( new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            while(shouldContinue){

                int DELAY = 60000;
                SystemClock.sleep(DELAY);
                                    /**
                                      ** I update my Database every 60 seconds
                                      **
                                      */
                          });
        t.start();


          //                 .......

       public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if( t.isAlive()) {
        shouldContinue = false;
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And this is MyMainActivity.class

```
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
               if( isMyServiceRunning() == true){    

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i= new Intent(this, MyService.class);

        stopService(i);
    }

      protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if( isMyServiceRunning() == false){
        Intent i= new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(i);

    }
    super.onDestroy();
}



     private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank your very much!

Comment: Don't you think you got your start and stop service swapped? Shouldn't it be started in onCreate and stopped in onDestroy ?

Comment: Not an Android expert, but in the lines `Intent i= new Intent(this, MyService.class); stopService(i);` there's just no reference to the `Service` instance, only to the class... Maybe Android doesn't automagically find the correct instance and stop it...

Comment: No, I would like when I start the app, the service will stop and when I close my app, the service will start again. Because I do not want the app and the service conflict when they use my database SQLite at the same time

Comment: Also, maybe `<a href="http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses(java.lang.String)">ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses (String packageName)</a> is what you're looking for. You can retrieve package name from `RunningServiceInfo service.service.getPackageName()`.

Comment: @yair I think that ok because as the following tutorial, they also only call the class name when they want stop service.http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm

Comment: @PhạmHuyThành : There is no reason to check to see if your `Service` is running or not. You can safely call `stopService` even if the `Service` isn't running. If that's the case, `stopService` does nothing. You also don't need to check if the `Service` is already running before you call `startService` - you can make multiple calls to `startService` and there will only every be one instance.

Comment: @Squonk: I know it but because in my app, I want to give users the function "turn on" or "turn off" the service, so I want to have a method like "isMyServiceRunning" so that I can ofrer a right interface. 
P/S:I'm sory for replying so late because my PC got a terrible problem

Answer (score -1):

Service runs on the same thread as your activities.

*Edit*

So when you `join()` in `onDestroy()`, you're going to wait for, at worst, 60 seconds..

Comment: This response doesn't solve the OP problem. It states something without backing it up with some proof. And yet again, the OP's `Service` code opens a new thread in its `onStartCommand` method.

Comment: @yair OP joins onDestory() (;